# Extracting data from JSON using GSON in java

Tags: java, json, google-maps, gson

Help please, this is my first time using JSON/GSON.
I've got this JSON data from google geocoding API and can't figure out how to extract "formatted_address" from it.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Google Building 41",
               "short_name" : "Google Bldg 41",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Google Bldg 41, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4228642,
                  "lng" : -122.0851557
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4221145,
                  "lng" : -122.0859841
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224082,
               "lng" : -122.0856086
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238383302915,
                  "lng" : -122.0842209197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211403697085,
                  "lng" : -122.0869188802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJxQvW8wK6j4AR3ukttGy3w2s",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

This is what I've tried but it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
public String getLocationData(String location) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(location);
            HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            request.connect();

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement content = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
            JsonObject jObject = content.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray jArray = jObject.getAsJsonArray("results");
            jObject = jArray.get(1).getAsJsonObject();

            String result = jObject.getAsString();

            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "fail";
    }
```

Comment: You can create a bean which corresponds to the above JSON response and then parse the above response to a java bean.

Comment: When you want to solve an exception, it is recommended to include its stacktrace, this way we can easily check where the error happens and in which context rather than having to read your whole code and guess what the error is.

Comment: In this case it looks like the `results` array only contains one element, which explains why calling `get(1)` will fail. I guess you wanted to write `get(0)` instead (arrays in Java are 0-indexed)

Comment: Yes it contains only one element, but I don't understand why. "results" should be an array of 5 elements: "address_components",  "formatted_address", "geometry" and so on...I'm trying to extract the 2nd element (formatted_address) but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: No, there's only a single element, whose fields are the ones you list. get the object, then get the fields with methods from this JsonObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only hazard a guess as to what your immediate error is without a stacktrace, but you're trying to access the second item of an array that only contains one item :

- the `results` array contains a single element (an object whose fields are the `address_components` array, `formatted_address`, `geometry`, `place_id` and `types`)
- you're trying to access its second element with `jArray.get(1)` (arrays in Java are 0-indexed)

This is a typical cause of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You probably want to access the only item with `jArray.get(0)` which you will be able to manipulate as a `JsonObject` whose fields you will be able to access.

Comment: I am trying to get to the formatted_address. I thought it's the second element of the results array, but apparently it's not. It's my first time using JSON and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @GoranKovač You've got an array which contains an object which has multiple fields such as `formatted_address`. What you're doing wrong is trying to access this `formatted_address` field from the array, while you should instead retrieve the object from the array, then the field's value from the object.

Comment: @GoranKovač It's the difference between `[{"field":"value"}]` and `{"field":"value"}` that you don't seem to get. In the second case you could directly get the field from the object as you try to do, but in the first you have to extract the object from the array and use that one to get the field. You're not manipulating a `JsonArray` for nothing : it has elements rather than fields, which could be primitive values or objects, but certainly not key/value pairs

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `jObject = jArray.get(1).getAsJsonObject();`, but your array only contains one element. Remember that arrays are **0-indexed** in Java. You should use `jObject = jArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();` instead.

Comment: I know it's 0-indexed. I'm trying to access "formatted_address", from "results" array. I don't understand why "results" only has 1 element when it should have 5.

Comment: @GoranKovač Because an object is meaningful and shouldn't be abstracted away. What if there was two objects in the array instead? Should you access the second object's `formatted_address` by getting the 6th item of the array? If there will always be a single object with these 5 fields then it's the array that should be removed, not the object

Comment: @GoranKovač You should add some `Sysout` (or even better, use a debugger) and check the value of your differents elements (`JSONElement`, `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`), and you'll understand what's happening instantly

Answer (score 0):

```
//URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7001/JMR_SERVICE/services/CalSerice?wsdl");

URL endPointUrl= new URL("http://192.168.0.161:7200/JMR_SERVICE/services/CalSerice?wsdl");

org.apache.axis.client.Service service=new  org.apache.axis.client.Service();


CalSericeSoapBindingStub stub=new CalSericeSoapBindingStub( endPointUrl,service);

String msg=stub.hello("hello how are you..............?");
String resp=stub.getID("ADMINUSER4");
```

Comment: it's very simple to call server side services in soap .. it's working very nice if you need pls take it and just copy....

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Dao {        
    String result="";
    public String  getDetails(int empid)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","om");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("connected data base");

        try
        {
            //stmt.execute("create table com (sno int,name varchar(90),age int)");
            System.out.println("connection is established");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement psmt=con.prepareStatement("select name from emp122 where id=id");
            //psmt.setInt(2,id);

            String query="select name from  emp120 where id='emid'";
            ResultSet rs=psmt.executeQuery();
            //String result="";
            while(rs.next())
            {
                result=rs.getString(1);
            }
            System.out.println(result);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "Not Record found";
        }


        return result;

   }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getconnection(String id)throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        System.out.println("collection jdbc");
        ArrayList ls=new ArrayList();

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.92:1521:FCARB01","EODMS","eodms");
        System.out.println("connected data base");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String sql="select QRY_TEXT from EOD_QRY_EXEC_LOG where OPERATOR_ID ='"+id+"'";
        System.out.println("fetching value....");
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        System.out.println("resulsetmetadata");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
        int a=rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
            {
                ls.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
        }

        return ls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're answering to the correct question? What does it have to do with databases?